# How to get a div's text value with react testing library?

Tags: html, reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

```
            <a className="stats__back" href="./..">
                &#129044;
            </a>
            <div className="profile-heading">ACCOUNT</div>
            <div className="profile-header">
                <div className="profile-avatar">
                    <img className="account-avatar" src={`./images/avatar${avatar}.png`} alt="User's avatar" width="150" height="150" />
                </div> 
                <div className="profile-header-info"> 
                    <div className="profile-username">{userName}</div>
                    <div className="profile-creation-date">
```

This is the part of the code I'm working on, and I'm trying to get access to div with className="profil-username" for unit test.

Here is how my test looks:

```
test('New user name is set after user name edition.', () => {
    act(() => {
        ReactDOM.render(<Account/>, container);
    });

    let profileUserName = container.querySelector("div.profile-username");
    let editButton = container.querySelector('.edition-text');
    let editUserName = container.querySelector('.account_modal-nick-input');
    let okButton = container.querySelector('.modal-button-save');
    let newUserName = "newUserName";

    fireEvent.click(editButton);
    fireEvent.change(editUserName, {target: {value: newUserName}});
    fireEvent.click(okButton);

    expect(profileUserName.value).toBe(newUserName);
});
```

So generally speaking I'm totally new to react and generally unit tests, and my final question is: How to get this particularry div using querySelector and how to call his value after this, is this just by writing divContainerVariableName.value or something else

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const profileUserName = container.querySelector("div.profile-username");
expect(profileUserName.textContent).toBe(newUserName);
```

If you have more than one `.profile-username`, it will get the first one appears in the dom tree.

You should first check if you have targeted the correct dom element first, then consider getting it's text context.

Comment: .toHaveTextContent() worked for me.